# Recursive definition of a language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, formal-languages

Define recursively the language L of all finite strings over the alphabet Σ={a b} satisfying both criteria:

1. All words in L contain the substring aa an odd number of times.
2. All words in L are such that they do not contain substrings comprising three or more consecutive copies of the letter a (i.e. the words in L do not contain the substring aaa.).

I first wrote the language in lexicographical order then produced the following recursive definition:

rule 1: aa is L

rule 2: if w is a word in L then so is:

wb, bw, wba, abw, aabwbaa

when I recursively go through this definition I think it works, however it does not seem as 'clean' as the examples given in textbooks, is there something I have missed?

Comment: You should add the base case $aa$ or an empty language will also be a solution.

Comment: Your definition includes "aabbb"

Comment: @DanielV "aabbb" does satisfy both criteria, i.e. the number of "aa" is odd(1) and the word does not contain the substring "aaa"

Comment: It does indeed work: it clearly generates only words of $L$, and it’s not hard to prove by induction on the length of the word that it generates every word of $L$. I don’t offhand see a simpler description.

Comment: @user4271816 Ah I misread the condition (2)

Comment: If you *really* want to define it recursively, then you can define $$S \in L \iff S \in L$$ no one said you had to identify an ordinal.